# How to javascript submit in the presence of an input id equal to 'submit'

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, namespaces

I've been binding submit events to forms, and ensuring that they do not break the form, using jQuery like this:

```
jQuery('form').submit(function(e){
    var form = this;
    e.preventDefault(); 
    alert('1');
    setTimeout(function() {   
        alert('2');
        form.submit();
        }, 1000);

    });
```

This is all good and well, except, if for some reason a front end developer gave a child input of this form an id of ="submit", this breaks, as `form.submit()` throws a JavaScript error (In Chrome, 'Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object # is not a function').

You can see an example of that happening here: http://jsfiddle.net/q68ky/ (Here's the behavior if there's no `<input id="submit">`: http://jsfiddle.net/JpXzL/

Now, I know I can prevent this from binding on forms that have children with an id of 'submit' with `jQuery('form').not(:has('#submit')).submit()`, and the form will process just fine, but my binding will never fire for those forms.

So, the question: How can I safely bind this jQuery function to all forms, including those with `<input id="submit">`?

EDIT: Worth noting that this problem doesn't go away if I unbind the submit handler and then trigger a jQuery submit on `jQuery(form)`.

Comment: I know an ideal world, I should never create `id="submit"` on an input form, but I can't guarantee that it won't exist.

Comment: @ys, you do understand that this code will result in an endless loop right ?

Comment: @Gaby no, `form.submit()` is triggering submit on the DOM element, not the jQuery element. if it was `$(form).submit();` you'd be right, and I'd need to unbind the jQuery handler, like here: jsfiddle.net/LKUhV. Also, as you see on the original jsfiddle, it doesn't result in an infinite loop of `alert()` being triggered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I can think of:

```
(function () {
    var method;

    window.submit = function (theForm) {
        if (!method) {
            method = document.createElement("form").submit;
        }

        method.call(theForm);
    };
}());
```

Then call `submit(theFormYouWantToSubmit)`.

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/q68ky/2/

**Edit: To provide some explanation as to what this does....**

This method creates a new form element (`document.createElement("form")`), and stores a reference to the "submit" attribute of it (`method = document.createElement("form").submit`). Because this is a newly created form element, with no child nodes, we can guarantee that the "submit" attribute is actually the "submit" method we need, rather than a child node with an id/name of "submit".

We then use the [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method (part of `Function.prototype`), which sets the context of the `submit` method to the form we want to submit, rather than the `window` object, which is what it would otherwise be on.

The rest of the gubbins in the snippet caches the `submit` method, so that all of this (albeit small) overhead does not take place every time you want to submit the form, and captures the cached method in a local scope, instead of holding it in the global scope and polluting the global namespace.

Comment: Apparently a jQuery committer tried this out, but it created some IE6 problems. http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1414 They've switched this to 'Won't Fix'.

Answer (score 4):

As this is actually a non-jQuery problem, here is a non-jQuery solution:

```
HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.call(form);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/A6vuq/1/)

Reference: [`HTMLFormElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLFormElement)

**Update:** [Access to the DOM prototypes is only possible in IE8+.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd282900(VS.85).aspx#domproto) *(and that is probably the reason why jQuery does not use it).*

[@Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465028/how-to-javascript-submit-in-the-presence-of-an-input-id-equal-to-submit/4465184#4465184) instead should work in any browser

Comment: Clean, I like it. Are there any drawbacks to using this more widely? And, further, why doesn't jQuery use this for `submit()`?

Comment: @yc: Well, I am always unsure how IE implements all these things. But I have no IE here to test... The method itself (getting the original method from the prototype) is used widely used to avoid exactly this situations (overwriting the property).

Comment: "I have no IE here to test..." - what heaven is this and how do I get there?

Comment: @ScottSEA: Get a Mac ;) (or any UNIX/Linux distribution and never install Windows again!)

Answer (score 2):

In addition the problem I identified in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465028/how-to-javascript-submit-in-the-presence-of-an-input-id-equal-to-submit/4465171#4465171), there is an open jQuery bug exacerbating the issue:

> .SUBMIT() CAN FAIL IF SOMETHING HAS ID="SUBMIT"
>
> If an element with an ID of submit
>   exists in a form, .submit() can fail.
>   It's important that this function (in
>   particular) work correctly.

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1414

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `form.submit();`, you need

```
$(form).submit();
```

This is because `form` is just the bare DOM element, while `$(form)` is the jQuery object. Calling `form.submit()` is trying to access the `submit` property of `form`. Since it doesn't have one, it's defaulting to the old-school behavior of getting the child element whose `id` is `submit` (hence the "is not a function" error).

Comment: @Emmett can you edit this answer to reflect your change of heart? :)

Comment: @yc It's not really a *change of heart*. There are TWO problems. The first one, which I describe in this answer, is causing the "is not a function" error. The second problem is the jQuery bug. If you're looking for an answer to mark as accepted, may I humbly suggest my other answer ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465028/how-to-javascript-submit-in-the-presence-of-an-input-id-equal-to-submit/4465171#4465171

Answer (score -1):

The error occurs if a form element's name or id is 'submit'.  It looks like it's an issue with jQuery.

Comment: nothing to do with jQuery. problem is that the . notations will find the element with id submit (*as it is a property of the form*) instead of the method..