# How dangerous is e.preventDefault();, and can it be replaced by keydown/mousedown tracking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, analytics, jquery-events

I'm working on a tracking script for a fairly sophisticated CRM for tracking form actions in Google Analytics. I'm trying to balance the desire to track form actions accurately with the **need** to never prevent a form from not working.

Now, I know that doing something like this doesn't work.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
 _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Form', 'Submit', $(this).attr('action')]);
});
```

The DOM unloads before this has a chance to process.

So, a lot of sample code recommends something like this:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var form = this; 
 _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Form', 'Submit', $(this).attr('action')]);
//...do some other tracking stuff...
setTimeout(function(){
form.submit();
}, 400);
});
```

This is reliable in [most cases](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4465028/172322), but it makes me nervous. What if something happens between `e.preventDefault();`and when I get around to triggering the DOM based submit? I've totally broken the form.

I've been poking around some other analytics implementations, and I've noticed [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/qV3TC/1/):

```
$('form').mousedown(function(){
 _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Form', 'Submit', $(this).attr('action')]);
});
$('form').keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which===13) //if the keydown is the enter key
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Form', 'Submit', $(this).attr('action')]);
});
```

Basically, instead of interrupting the form submit, preempting it by assuming that if someone is mousing down or keying down on Enter, than that form is submitted. Obviously, this will result in a certain amount of false positives, but it completely eliminates use of `e.preventDefault();`, which in my mind eliminates the risk that I might ever prevent a form from successfully submitting.

So, my question:

- Is it possible to take the standard
  form tracking snippet and prevent it
  from *ever* fully preventing the form
  from submitting?
- Is the
  mousedown/keydown alternative viable?
- Are there any submission cases it may miss? Specifically, are there other ways to end up submitting besides the mouse and the keyboard enter? And will the browser always have time to process javascript before beginning to unload the page?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Them fellers over at that there Googleplex are awful bright and they figgered some day somethin' like this was bound to happen and now, sure enough, it has.  Why don't you give this a good try:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = this; 
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Form', 'Submit', $(this).attr('action')]);
  //...do some other tracking stuff...
  _gaq.push(function(){
     form.submit();
    });
  });
```

That `_gaq.push` thigamajigger executes its elements sequentially, so you should be jest fine.

And no, I don't know why I suddenly started talking like this.

Comment: Mmmm, let me try again.  The solution of just waiting an arbitrary amount of time and assuming that it is now safe to leave the page is *guaranteed* to either (a) waste the users time or (b) fail by leaving to early (the odds you will guess correctly every time can be disregarded).  Instead you need a technique whereby you are notified when tracking is complete.  Fortunately, the Google Analytics Queue provides that: all you have to do is push a function object at the end of the queue.  Once everything ahead of it in the queue has completed, that function will be executed and submit your form.

Comment: I realize now you may also be worried about the "some tracking stuff" failing and thereby cause the form to never be submitted.  For that your two choices are, wrap all the code but the submit in a try-except block, which is safe by sloppy, or simple don't call preventDefault until the last line of the function, so if there's an error, it won't be called and the submission *should* still go through, which is elegant but should be carefully tested.

Comment: `_gaq.push((function(){` should be `_gaq.push(function(){`

Answer (score 3):

I use a different approach, and generate the event tracking script in the page resulting from the submit. You could call it *deferred event tracking*.

I wrote a [blog post](http://technomilk.wordpress.com/2010/12/05/tracking-events-with-google-analytics-in-struts-actions/) with all details about my approach to event tracking in backend actions. It is biased towards Java-Struts, but you can get the general idea.

The rationale is that I want to track some things after they happened at the server side. In this kind of case, after the form was submitted and processed by the server.

What I do (very summarized):

- Store events in an object tied to the session (a list/queue)
- Flush these events upon the next page render (generate the javascript and empty the queue)

Answer (score 3):

If you must have forms always work but tracking can be sacrificed if absolutely necessary,  you could just try/catch it.

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    try{
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = this; 
         _gaq.push('_trackEvent', 'Form', 'Submit', $(this).attr('action'));
        //...do some other tracking stuff...
        setTimeout(function(){
            form.submit();
        }, 400);
    } catch (e) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Implemented this solution for the same problem and worked well. Thanks. What is the exact reason that google has an issue with form submits and event tracking? At first I thought it was due to the form submission occurring and page reloading too fast for the data to be sent to Google, but even after I added setTimeout logic, it was still happening. Only when I added the `e.preventDefault` call did everything start working again.

Comment: Setting the timeout is only half the story. If you set a timeout for the form submit, but don't e.preventDefault, then you are letting the form submission happen immediately (as the default of the event), which still preempts the call to analytics.

Answer (score 1):

`e.preventDefault()` doesn't have to be right at the beginning of the function call. Why not just have an `if` statement to verify if everything is working correctly, and only call `e.preventDefault()` if it does. If any function in the chain doesn't return the expected result, set a `submitted` variable to `false`, and don't prevent the default.

This might be a little more difficult to handle when it comes to anything asynchronous (such as your `setTimeout`, but there will be ways to make fairly sure, depending on what your code looks like. So you can check if methods exist with `if (_gaq.push)` (for example). You can't make 100% sure without testing every single combination in every browser, but I reckon you can get a pretty satisfactory result with this.

Answer (score 0):

**Another approach:**

```
var pageTracker;
_gaq.push(function() {
    pageTracker = _gat._getTrackerByName();
});

$('form').submit(function(e){
    pageTracker._trackEvent('Form', 'Submit', $(this).attr('action'));
};
```

I would guess this way _trackEvent would be synchronous but I haven't tested it.

Comment: GA being asynchronous isn't the problem. The asynchronous aspect refers to the loading of the script initially, not to subsequent calls. Once ga.js loads, `_gaq.push('_trackEvent',...)` calls execute just as quickly as `pageTracker._trackEvent(...)`

Comment: If that is the case you could consider writing your own trackEvent function with a onload handler attached to the __utm.gif image, however I think onload handlers for images aren't that reliable in some browser (e.g. when loaded from cache not fired, but from cache loading should never happen in this case anyways). A old pageTrack function: http://code.google.com/p/google-analytics-js/source/browse/trunk/gajs.js?r=3

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you can't just issue the call to Google Analytics from the server side based on the POST that it receives?

I don't know what your system is built in, but for instance, this PHP project would issue a call to GA, thus removing the problem of the DOM unloading, the need to break the form, and so on.

http://code.google.com/p/serversidegoogleanalytics/

I realise that you might need to capture a cookie - you might write the value into a hidden field in the form before it is submitted?

Comment: This could work for some people, but unfortunately, in this CMS environment, I don't have access to server side scripting. Everything needs to be done in JavaScript.

Comment: And even if you could, *you* are paying for the servers; your millions of customers each bring his own client.

Comment: For posterity: the project linked in this answer has been retired; instead see the newer project http://code.google.com/p/php-ga/

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @Malvolio's answer:
Once gaq sends the event the next item in the queue will process. This means that the event HTTP request may abort on the client side, but GA will receive the request. Don't worry about blocking script execution until the response finishes. It is a fire and forget scenario.