# Google analytics _trackPageview callback

Tags: google-analytics

Is there a way to define a callback for when _trackPageview completes?

I have the following code to track when a user logs into my site, and to refresh the page afterwards:

```
pageTracker._trackPageview('/login/complete');
location.reload(true);
```

The problem with the above code is that _trackPageview attaches an image to the DOM and there's no guarantee that the image loads before the page refreshes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overwriting the current `Image()` function in the page is one solution:

```
  var oldImage = window.Image;
  window.Image = function()
  {
      var self = this;
      var theImage = new oldImage();
      $(theImage).load(function(){
          // Analytics ajax finished
          // Do something here (submit the form or whatever)
      });
      return theImage;
  };
```

But I actually think that Malvolio has a [better solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551218/how-dangerous-is-e-preventdefault-and-can-it-be-replaced-by-keydown-mousedown/4568101#4568101) using `_gaq.push()` that will work for what you need.

Comment: +1. This is a brilliant answer. Perhaps might be worth wrapping it in a `try/catch`, so that if something in the tracking code fails, it still returns an image?

Comment: I've used the setTimeout method, but I have to second that this is absolutely brilliant and works like a charm. If it helps to follow this was my usage: $(theImage).load(function(){
           alert( $(this).attr("src") );
           /* the google analytics tracker image loaded, redirect */
    window.location.href = '<%=tabURL%>';
       });

Answer (score 1):

Most implementations I've seen get around this problem by putting the reload/redirect in a setTimeout() of 500ms-1s