# jQuery: Weirdest issue with submitting a form with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I've been stuck with this issue for almost 3 days!

I have an input button: `<input type="button" id="submit" value="Upload"/>`
Using jQuery 1.6.1, in the document.ready, I'm binding the button to submit the form like this:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
     $('form').submit();
});
```

Using FireBug, the line `$('form').submit()`; causes an error with jquery!
After 3 days of trying to figure out the issue, it seems that naming the input button id="submit" is what's causing the bug! When I changed the id to something else, it worked!

Any technical explanation to this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to javascript submit in the presence of an input id equal to 'submit'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465028/how-to-javascript-submit-in-the-presence-of-an-input-id-equal-to-submit)

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery form submit() is not working in IE6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445850/jquery-form-submit-is-not-working-in-ie6)

Comment: I'm testing on Safari, Chromo and FireFox, all of them fail :S

Answer (score 0):

This has something to do with the browser. The browser see the input as an submit button when defining an Id with `submit`. simply use this code will solve the problem:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
     $('form').submit();
     return false;
});
```

Comment: That won't fix the problem. jQuery's submit methods calls `submit` internally.